# How to update array of options in WordPress network admin plugin

Tags: wordpress, api, settings, multisite

I'm writing a network plugin for a multisite that loops through an array of block names and creates a checkbox input for each. It successfully stores all options in the network option as a serialized array. However, it isn't updating the options on the page -- i.e. clicked checkboxes aren't retained when the update refreshes the page.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Here's the callback function and the bit of the Settings API that calls it:

```
    add_settings_field(
        $GLOBALS[ 'whitelisted_blocks' ],   // id of field
        __( '', 'multisite-settings' ),         // title of field to display
        'multisite_settings_checkbox_callback', // callback function
        $main_blocks_settings_slug,       // page to display it on
        'main-blocks-section'
    );
   
    // callback function for settings field (main site option) 
    function multisite_settings_checkbox_callback() {
        $whitelist_options = $GLOBALS[ 'whitelisted_blocks' ];

        // callback function for add_settings_option
        function individual_settings_checkbox_callback( $key, $block_name, $whitelist_options ) {
    
            $array_value = array();
            if( isset( $whitelist_options['checkboxes_field'] ) && ! empty($whitelist_options['checkboxes_field'] ) ) {
                $array_value = $whitelist_options[ 'checkboxes_field'];
            }

            $html = '<input type="checkbox" 
                name="' . $whitelist_options . '[checkboxes_field]['. $block_name .']" 
                id="block_checkbox_' . $block_name . '"
                "value="on"' . checked( "on", $array_value[$block_name], false ) . '/>';

            $html .= '<label for="block_checkbox_' . $block_name . '">' . $block_name . '</label>';   
            $html .= '<br>';
            echo $html;
        }

        // get list of all registered blocks and add to variable (array)
        $main_blocks_registry = get_all_blocks();

        // then for each item in array, send to callback functions to add settings field and create html. 
        foreach( $main_blocks_registry as $key=>$name ) {
            // If plugin settings don't exist, create them
            individual_settings_checkbox_callback( $key, $name, $whitelist_options );   
        }
        // register setting for newly created settings option
        register_setting( 'main-blocks-section', $GLOBALS[ 'whitelisted_blocks' ] );
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm attempting to single out the current settings option in the array. I've tried using 'in_array' to determine whether an option is in the array, and updating the 'checked', but that didn't work.

Thanks for any help!